# How i convert 5.212217e-17 to regular number?

Tags: r

I have this number outputed in r: 5.212217e-17.

How i convert it to regular number?

Comment: Please specify "regular number". How do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Its 0.00000000000000005212217 - is that really better than using exponential (e-17) notation?

Comment: @krlmlr like Spacedman wrote. that's how i want it to look like.

Comment: Can we ask why? Are you feeding it to some other software? There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @Spacedman No i am not feeding it in another softwer. I write a project in statistic, and i need the precise number.

Comment: Then I admire your confidence in your calculation if you think you can tell the difference between 5.2 x 10^-17, 5.21 x 10^-17, and zero.

Comment: I'm with @Spacedman -- the correct representation is `0`

Comment: Unless this is the charge on 500 electrons in -coulombs.

Comment: This might be a p-value. Then a better representation would be something like p < 0.001.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
     options(scipen=999)
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you interested in how it is displayed or the precision to which R stores decimals?

If you simply want to display the number in your console:

```
format(5.212217e-17, scientific = FALSE)
```